# Remote server command line matlab - how to run my method?

Tags: matlab

I've seen a bunch of copies of this question but none of them have concrete answers.

I know that in the GUI, I load the file and then type `myfunc(myargs)`, but I only have an ssh connection to the server I'm connecting to, so I only have command line matlab.

Is there a way to load (I'm thinking import - that didn't work) the file so that I can call its functions? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I'm not seeing where the problem is.   From the matlab command-line, sure, you can call arbitrary functions with arbitrary arguments, e.g. `myfunc(myargs)`.  And you can load data from a `.mat` file with `load` (or from other formats with various other commands).  Do you have some specific requirement beyond that..?  When you say, "load the file", what kind of file are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out - the name of the function must be the name of the file.

`PATH` must also contain `.`, but it appears as though this is default in matlab.

I am still interested in finding a way to pack (and call) multiple functions within the same file.